# How to initialize biases in a Keras model?

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning, keras

I am trying to build a synthetic model in Keras, and I need to assign values for the weights and biases. Assigning the weights is easy, I am using the instructions provided here: https://keras.io/initializations/.
However, I could not find any instructions on how to assign the biases. Any ideas?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can find the answer here.
https://keras.io/layers/core/

> **weights**: list of Numpy arrays to set as initial weights. The list
>   should have 2 elements, of shape  (input_dim, output_dim) and
>   (output_dim,) for weights and biases respectively.

When adding a new layer, you can define the argument "weights", a list that contains initial **w** and **b** with shape speicified.

`model.add(Dense(50, input_dim= X_train.shape[1], weights = [np.zeros([692, 50]), np.zeros(50)]))`

Comment: Initializing all weights to zeros (or for that matter, to any value where all neurons are identical) is a really bad idea. A random_normal (or truncated_normal) initializer should be used with a bias depending on the activation function used.

Comment: I agree with @Peteris here. You should at least initialise kernel weights to something other than zeros.

Answer (score 21):

You can also use bias_initializer like this:

```
model.add(Dense(64,
                kernel_initializer='random_uniform',
                bias_initializer='zeros')
```

This is from https://keras.io/initializers/

Comment: i have the weight and bios in numpy array can use kernel_initializer to add them directly

Answer (score 5):

Initialize biases with small positive value such as 0.1

> Since we're using ReLU neurons, it is also good practice to initialize them with a slightly positive initial bias to avoid "dead neurons".

Answer (score 5):

Weight and bias initialization for each layer can be set via `kernel_initializer` and `bias_initializer` keyword arguments respectively within `layers.Dense()`. If undefined by user, default settings of `kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform'` and `bias_initializer='zeros'` are applied.

For example, if you wanted to initialize a layer's weight initialization to random uniform instead of glorot and bias initialization to 0.1 instead of 0, you could define a given layer as follows:

```
from keras import layers, initializers

layer = layers.Dense(64,
                     activation='relu',
                     kernel_initializer='random_uniform',
                     bias_initializer=initializers.Constant(0.1))(previous_layer)
```

See [layers/core/](https://keras.io/layers/core/) for details on Dense layer keyword arguments and [initializers/](https://keras.io/initializers/) for preset and customizable initializer options